# objective c - logout functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented a simple login page, where the user logs in with valid credentials. I then set the `NSUserDefauts` and navigate them to the "HOME" screen. I'm now trying to implement a logout button.

Below is how I return back to the login screen and clear my `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, when the app navigates back to the login screen, the username and password is filled in from previous login. I tried setting it to `@""` in `viewDidAppear` but there's a delay before it's set to empty strings.

How can I dismiss the viewcontroller so that everything is reset when returned to the login screen?

Comment: Use `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 way to do it.
Suppose there are 2 ViewController
LoginViewController and the SecondViewController

1.
in LoginViewController you can remove the text in username and password in viewDidDisappear.

2.
or instead of calling viewDidAppear in LoginViewController.
Call viewWillAppear will do the trick.